# How to "properly" print a list?

Tags: python, string

So I have a list:

```
['x', 3, 'b']
```

And I want the output to be:

```
[x, 3, b]
```

How can I do this in python?

If I do `str(['x', 3, 'b'])`, I get one with quotes, but I don't want quotes.

Comment: To explain why the list isn't "properly" printed, `print(["Sam"])` calls `repr("Sam")`, which returns `'Sam'` (with the quotes), unlike when you call `print("Sam")` and python calls `str("Sam")` which returns `Sam` (without the quotes). See [difference between `str` and `repr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) or [Python `str` and `list`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727761/python-str-and-lists) for more info.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
mylist = ['x', 3, 'b']
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, mylist))
```

In Python 3 (where `print` is a builtin function and not a syntax feature anymore):

```
mylist = ['x', 3, 'b']
print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, mylist)))
```

Both return:

```
[x, 3, b]
```

This is using the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to call str for each element of *mylist*, creating a new list of strings that is then joined into one string with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join). Then, the `%` string formatting operator substitutes the string in instead of `%s` in `"[%s]"`.

Comment: Thank you that works great. Can you explain a bit in detail on what are you doing in the second line? I am new to python.

Comment: He is using the `map` function to call `str` for each element of `mylist`, creating a new list of strings that he then joins into one string with `str.join`. Then, he uses the `%` string formatting operator to substitute the string in instead of `%s` in `"[%s]"`.

Comment: Another way to do it that's maybe a bit more modern:

`"[{0}]".format(", ".join(str(i) for i in mylist))`

Comment: i tend to prefer `map(f, xs)` (or `imap` in python2.x) over `(f(x) for x in xs)`, when `f` is a predefined callable; that tends to execute fewer bytecodes, and is usually more compact.  Certainly *dont* `map(lambda x:..., xs)` thats much worse than `(... for x in xs)`

Comment: @user1767754: really?  Link?

Comment: @li.davidm I included your explanation in the answer itself, since it is useful and was severly upvoted. Thanks for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: what about print(*mylist, sep=",")?¿?¿

Comment: @user1767754 According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), the only related things that seem to be deprecated are related to bytes: `b'%s'` and `b'%r'`.

Answer (score 22):

This is simple code, so if you are new you should understand it easily enough.

```
mylist = ["x", 3, "b"]
for items in mylist:
    print(items)
```

It prints all of them without quotes, like you wanted.

Answer (score 20):

Using only print:

```
>>> l = ['x', 3, 'b']
>>> print(*l, sep='\n')
x
3
b
>>> print(*l, sep=', ')
x, 3, b
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Python3:

```
print('[',end='');print(*L, sep=', ', end='');print(']')
```

Comment: what does print(*L) do here?

Comment: @sandeeps: see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls

Comment: I am confused by this. Is the long data type filtering the list somehow?

Comment: A more concise version would be `print(end='['); print(*l, sep=', ', end=']\n')`

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `map`, I'd recommend using a generator expression with the capability of `join` to accept an iterator:

```
def get_nice_string(list_or_iterator):
    return "[" + ", ".join( str(x) for x in list_or_iterator) + "]"
```

Here, `join` is a member function of the string class `str`. It takes one argument: a list (or iterator) of strings, then returns a new string with all of the elements concatenated by, in this case, `,`.

Comment: A good optimization for Python 2, since map returns a list in 2.x. It returns a generator in 3.x, so it doesn't help as much there.

Comment: I would do return ``", ".join( str(x) for x in list_or_iterator).join('[]')``

Comment: @eyquem: Clever, I've not seen join used like that before. Still, that is a little more opaque to a beginner (since you're using the property that a string is an iterable container of one-character strings).

Answer (score 6):

You can delete all unwanted characters from a string using its [`translate()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) with `None` for the *`table`* argument followed by a string containing the character(s) you want removed for its *`deletechars`* argument.

```
lst = ['x', 3, 'b']

print str(lst).translate(None, "'")

# [x, 3, b]
```

If you're using a version of Python before 2.6, you'll need to use the `string` module's `translate()` function instead because the ability to pass `None` as the *`table`* argument wasn't added until Python 2.6. Using it looks like this:

```
import string

print string.translate(str(lst), None, "'")
```

Using the `string.translate()` function will also work in 2.6+, so using it might be preferable.

Comment: Alas : ``lst = ["it isn't", 3, 'b']`` ==> ``["it isnt", 3, b]`` and also with ``lst = ['it isn\'t', 3, 'b']``

Comment: @eyquem: Yes, avoiding the deletion of characters that are actually be part of your data (rather than strictly being used to delimit it) would naturally require slightly more elaborate/different logic if it's a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an interactive session showing some of the steps in @TokenMacGuy's one-liner. First he uses the `map` function to convert each item in the list to a string (actually, he's making a new list, not converting the items in the old list). Then he's using the string method `join` to combine those strings with `', '` between them. The rest is just string formatting, which is pretty straightforward. (Edit: this instance is straightforward; string formatting in general can be somewhat complex.)

Note that using `join` is a simple and efficient way to build up a string from several substrings, much more efficient than doing it by successively adding strings to strings, which involves a lot of copying behind the scenes.

```
>>> mylist = ['x', 3, 'b']
>>> m = map(str, mylist)
>>> m
['x', '3', 'b']
>>> j = ', '.join(m)
>>> j
'x, 3, b'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `.format` for string formatting,**

```
mylist = ['x', 3, 'b']
print("[{0}]".format(', '.join(map(str, mylist))))
```

**Output:**

```
[x, 3, b]
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. `map` is used to map each element of the list to `string` type.
2. The elements are joined together into a string with `,` as separator.
3. We use `[` and `]` in the print statement to show the list braces.

Reference: 
[`.format` for string formatting PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: Great! I find using `.format` the most pythonic way. But, of course, I accept disagreements. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by @AniMenon to write a pythonic more general solution.

```
mylist = ['x', 3, 'b']
print('[{}]'.format(', '.join(map('{}'.format, mylist))))
```

It only uses the `format` method. No trace of `str`, and it allows for the fine tuning of the elements format.
For example, if you have float numbers as elements of the list, you can adjust their format, by adding a conversion specifier, in this case `:.2f`

```
mylist = [1.8493849, -6.329323, 4000.21222111]
print("[{}]".format(', '.join(map('{:.2f}'.format, mylist))))
```

The output is quite decent:

```
[1.85, -6.33, 4000.21]
```