# Why Columbus is first in Python?

Tags: python, list

When I executed below code in [Codecademy Labs](http://labs.codecademy.com) :-

```
 names = [Adam,"Alex","Mariah","Martine","Columbus"]

 for Adam in names:

   print Adam
```

It prints:-

```
Columbus

Alex

Mariah

Martine

Columbus
```

Now, I want to ask why "Columbus" is at the top position. I know I used an empty variable "Adam" in the list and in "for loop" as same. It should be a "syntax error" due to same variable usage in list as well as in "for loop" then why the last element of that list prints out at first as well at last.

Comment: Presumably you assigned the value `"Columbus"` to the variable `Adam` at some earlier stage.

Comment: I think because `Adam` variable points to string "Columbus"!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan You mean that it is because of Codecademy labs fault?

Comment: @BrenBarn I think you should post your comment as an answer as it is the only plausible explanation.

Comment: @DeveshSaini What I mean `print Adam` will print first string in `names` list and in your `names` list first string in not a constant string literal but a reference-variable `Adam`, first time string will be printed that is pointed my `names[0]`

Comment: @AlienArrays So, Assume "Columbus" as "Raymond".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you're running the same code multiple times.

```
>>> Adam = '' # <--- except this line.
>>> names = [Adam,"Alex","Mariah","Martine","Columbus"]
>>> for Adam in names:
...     print Adam
...

Alex
Mariah
Martine
Columbus
```

After the for loop `Adam` reference `"Columbus"` (the last element of the list), because target variable (`Adam`) is not delete after the loop:

```
>>> Adam
'Columbus'
```

Running same code produce what you see:

```
>>> names = [Adam,"Alex","Mariah","Martine","Columbus"]
>>> for Adam in names:
...     print Adam
...
Columbus
Alex
Mariah
Martine
Columbus
```

Using same variable for `for` target variable does not cause SyntaxError. The variable is just overwritten.

[image]

Comment: seems like the python interpreter in codeacademy lab didn't have the same effect.

Comment: http://labs.codecademy.com/BvO1#:workspace, I think the only that `Adam =Colubus` is that the list is reinitialized again.

Comment: @alvas, I could reproduce. See the screenshot I just added to the answer.

Comment: @falsetru, yeah, the `names` list got to be reinitialized for the "bug" to appear =)

Comment: @alvas, I say so from the beginning. It's not a bug. See [`for` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement). QUOTE: The target list is not deleted when the loop is finished, ...

Comment: pardon the terms, it's a "gotcha"!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the problem 1 of why "Columbus" prints first?

I really don't know how you did it, my attempt shows that it prints in the order that the list is initialized, see [printing list in python properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445970/printing-list-in-python-properly) for how you can manipulate prints in python:

[image]

The answer to the second question of empty variable, I got a normal syntax error, see how variables work in python here: [Python variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007627/python-variable-declaration):

[image]

**To replicate the OP's error, `Adam = "Columbus"` will only be `True if the OP reinitialized the`names` list after the for loop:** see http://labs.codecademy.com/BvOl/1#:workspace

[image]

Surely using a local `Adam` in looping a for-loop is not unlike using `i`. After the for-loop, the `i` will take the value of the last item in the list.

```
>>> alist = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in alist:
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
4
>>> i
4
```

But when the next for-loop, the `i` will automatically be set to the first item in the list when the loop starts. But if you reinitialize the list after the first time you ran the for-loop, now the first item in the list would take the value of the last item:

```
>>> i = None
>>> alist = [i,2,3,4]
>>> for i in alist:
...     print i
... 
None
2
3
4
>>> i
4
>>> alist = [i,2,3,4]
>>> alist
[4, 2, 3, 4]
```