# Not getting the desired output using print()

Tags: python

My python code is as follows :

```
class Student():

        def __init__(self, name, branch, year):
            self.name = name
            self.branch = branch
            self.year = year
            # Variables name,branch and year are instance variables
            # Different objects like Student1, Student2 will have diff values of these variables.
            print('Student object is created for Student : ', name)

       def print_details(self):
            print('Name:', self.name)
            print('Branch:', self.branch)
            print('Year:', self.year)

Stud1 = Student('AAkash','ECE',2015)
Stud2 = Student('Vijay','IT',2017)

Stud1.print_details()
Stud2.print_details()
```

My output is :

```
('Student object is created for Student : ', 'AAkash')
('Student object is created for Student : ', 'Vijay')
('Name:', 'AAkash')
('Branch:', 'ECE')
('Year:', 2015)
('Name:', 'Vijay')
('Branch:', 'IT')
('Year:', 2017)
```

whereas in my required output, i want statements like :

```
Name : AAkash
Branch : CSE
```

Comment: Try deleting brackets from `print` statements

Comment: @MooingRawr With Python 2 he will get those brackets around output. I think he doesn't want them

Comment: @Georgy oh my mistake you are correct, shows how much I use Python 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print() is showing quotation marks in results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262379/print-is-showing-quotation-marks-in-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using python-3.x print syntax but you are probably just running python 2.7 . `print` in python2 isn't a function it's a statement, it only looks like a function.

when you do

```
print('Name:', self.name)
```

you're telling the print statement to print a tuple with 2 items in it - and that is exactly what it does

you can just remove the parenthesis and have it look like so:

```
print 'Name:', self.name
print 'Branch:', self.branch
print 'Year:', self.year
```

which would print what you want (actually print multiple items not the tuple itself)

**or**

you can get the python3 style print function in your code by importing it from future (in python 2.7):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and it will give you your desired output