# Display Python 2D list without commas, brackets, etc

Tags: python, list

I want to display a 2D list without brackets, commas, or any stuffs. I printed the content of the list using the following code:

```
print(ncA_string[a][0],ncA_string[a][1],ncA_string[a][2],ncA_string[a][3])
```

Unfortunately, however, it is showing the commas, and brackets. 
[Here's the picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVV1s.png)

I wanna display it like this: `((((((ab)c)d)e)`

I'm new to using python and I've tried using the join map but i couldn't understand it yet.

Can anyone teach me how to??

Thank you so much :))

Comment: Maybe try a little research first?  I googled "print a python list", which includes [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445970/printing-list-in-python-properly), the answers to which have several examples that may point you in the right direction.

Comment: @larsks what your said, was really the same thing as a LGTFY link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added. And those are considered rude, and impolite. Yes, he could have just googled the question, but you didn't have to tell him like that. Let's be nice, K?

Comment: Mr. Gooseberry, I see you're not terribly familiar with stackoverflow.  One of the things we ask is that people try to solve problems on their own *first*, and come here with specific technical questions ("My code looks like this, and while I expect `<`this output`>`, instead I get `<`this error`>`) rather than broad, "write my code for me" questions.  There are other places to go if you want people to write your code *for* you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten `ncA_string[a]` first. Try to use `flatten` function from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472461/1112457 . Then you can unpack the flattened list as arguments to the `print` function:

```
print(*flatten(ncA_string[a]))
```

or if you want to print it without spaces:

```
print(''.join(flatten(ncA_string[a])))
```