# Trying to get contents of list into one string for an email

Tags: python

I am trying to construct an email from selecting data from a database, this is working I am saving the data out to a file, what I am doing it constructing the body of the email, I have the first test in a varable and the closing of the email in a variable.

When I am trying to get the data from a text file as part of the body, I can print the text when adding to the email, I am getting it in a list format i.e [name, dob, etc] or I can get it to just show the last line of the text.

Can you please help to get these names listed, so the mail is all dynamic

Contents of the text file would be

Craig Richards 01/01/1970

Barny Rubble 02/02/1971

Fred Flintsone 03/03/1972

It is showing the mail body as 
Can I please order the licenses for the following students please
['Craig Richards 01/01/1970','Barny Rubble 02/02/1971','Fred Flintsone 03/03/1972']

What I would like is like it is listed and showed in the text file.
So it would say

Please can I order the licenses for the following students

Craig Richards 01/01/1970

Barny Rubble 02/02/1971

Fred Flintsone 03/03/1972

Regards

Craig

The code is

```
def sendMail(user,pwd,to,subject,text):
  msg = MIMEText(text)
  msg['From'] = 'craig@craig.com'
  msg['To'] = to
  msg['Subject'] = subject
  try:
    smtpServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.address','587')
    print "[+] Connecting to the Mail Server [+]"
    smtpServer.ehlo()
    print "[+] Encrypting the session [+]"
    smtpServer.starttls()
    smtpServer.ehlo()
    print "[+] Logging into the mail server [+]"
    smtpServer.login(user, pwd)
    print "[+] Sending your mail [+]"
    smtpServer.sendmail(user, to, msg.as_string())
    smtpServer.close()
    print "[+] Your mail has been sent [+]"
  except:
    print "[-] Your message failed to send [-]"

def database():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(master_db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    loc_stmt="SELECT first_name, surname,dob from student where     license_ordered = 'N';"
    cursor.execute(loc_stmt)
    part1="Can I please order the licenses for the following students please \n\n"
    part3="\n\nRegards\nCraig"
    os.remove(scripts+'/output/license_order.txt')
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row == None:
           break
        print row[0].ljust(15), row[1].ljust(15),row[2]
        f=open(scripts+'/output/license_order.txt','a')
        f.write(row[0]+'\t'+row[1]+'\t'+row[2]+'\n')
        f.flush()
        f.close()

    user = 'username'
    pwd = 'password'

    with open(scripts+'/output/license_order.txt','r') as myfile:
      data = myfile.read()
    mylist=data.splitlines()
    for part2 in mylist:
      print part2
    #message = part1 + str(mylist) + part3
    print part2
    message = part1 + part2 + part3
    sendMail(user, pwd, 'craig@craig.com','License Orders',message)

def main():
        global tdate
        tdate=strftime("%d-%m-%y")
        database()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting! Include a proper input/output example so we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller parts. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you're trying to print the list ['Bill', '2/3/1978', '980-555-1212'], I'd suggest you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445970/printing-list-in-python-properly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: I have added an example of the text file as it looks now

Comment: Shall I just put the snippet in about reading the file, would that help