# howto print list without brackets and comma python

Tags: python

```
ISBN = [int(e) for e in input("input ISBN :")]
sum = 10*ISBN[0]+9*ISBN[1]+8*ISBN[2]+7*ISBN[3]+6*ISBN[4]+5*ISBN[5]+4*ISBN[6]+3*ISBN[7]+2*ISBN[8]
for i in range(0,10):
    sum_check = sum + i
    if sum_check % 11 ==0: 
      print("n10 =",i)
       ISBN.append(i)
```

OUTPUT

```
n10 = 5
[0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 5]
```

**but i want this output**

020134525

Comment: `''.join(ISBN)`

Comment: print(*ISBN, sep=''). There are plenty of answer on this topic, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445970/how-to-properly-print-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "properly" print a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445970/how-to-properly-print-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print any list in python without spaces, commas and brackets simply do

```
print(*list_name,sep='')
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to `str()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the list AS IS, python will alway print it within brackets:

```
[0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 5]
```

If you want to get all the numbers together, it means you want to `join` the numbers in the list.

What you want to do is `join` the items in the list, like this:

```
result = ''.join(list)
```

The object `result` will be the numbers as you wanted, as:

```
020134525
```

Comment: List doesn't have a `join` method.

Comment: You're right, got confused with other languages. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if ISBN = [0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 5]

Then you can write

```
ISBN = [0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 5]
print(''.join(str(i) for i in ISBN))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `''.join(ISBN)`
Alternatively, instead of having `ISBN` as a list, make it `str`.

```
ISBN = ''
(your code)
ISBN+=i
```