# Get Value of Instance List as a String in python

Tags: python

Working with this code, and my output is not the list of strings, but instances.  Do I re-write my LineCount class to allow such behavior?

```
line_count =[]

class LineCount:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def set_x(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

# add a value
line_count.append(LineCount(1))

# print list - does not print our string values
print line_count
# [<__main__.LineCount instance at 0x1031d53f8>]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727761/python-str-and-lists

Comment: @TylerSebastian - tried that and got this error: TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: try fixing your indentation first.

Comment: `return str(self.x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your print statement to call the `get_x` function for each element in the list using a list comprehesion.

```
print [y.get_x() for y in line_count]
```

Comment: this worked and so did the solution from comment by @Tyler above