# I cant get the return function working

Tags: python

So, I'm making a text based game to learn the python language. and I can't get the return function working...

Here is my code;

```
class Weapon:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WoodenStaff(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Wooden Staff"
        self.description = "Basic Staff"
        self.damage = 5

inventory = [WoodenStaff()]
print (inventory)
```

After I run this I got:

```
[<__main__.WoodenStaff object at 0x000001E9F192CAC8>]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python \_\_str\_\_ and lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727761/python-str-and-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `__repr__` because your object is inside a list.

```
class Weapon:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class WoodenStaff(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Wooden Staff"
        self.description = "Basic Staff"
        self.damage = 5

inventory = [WoodenStaff()]
print (inventory)
>> [Wooden Staff]
```

Without implementing `__repr__`, you get the expected output if iterating over the list:

```
class Weapon:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WoodenStaff(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Wooden Staff"
        self.description = "Basic Staff"
        self.damage = 5

inventory = [WoodenStaff()]
for weapon in inventory:
    print(weapon)
>> Wooden Stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `__repr__` as well

```
 def __repr__(self):
      return self.name
```

e.g. -

```
>>> class Weapon:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.name
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return self.name
...
>>> class WoodenStaff(Weapon):
...      def __init__(self):
...         self.name = 'Foo'
...
>>> [WoodenStaff()]
[Foo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `__repr__` method to `WoodenStaff` Class

Comment: Could you add some explanation and maybe some sample code please?