# Does __str__ still work in python ver3? How do i convert object to string output?

Tags: string, python-3.x, class, object

I'm very new to python and django..When i tried to follow the tutorial on djangoproject.com i am unable to produce my object as a string despite trying different variations of the code including the following. I am using python 3x

Trial 1

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Trial 2

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        return str(Question)
```

Trial 3

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        print(Question)
```

Typing this

```
Question.objects.all()
```

Still shows

```
<QuerySet [<Question: Question object]>
```

Instead of

```
<QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>
```

Please help!!!!!

Comment: Lists use repr for their elements. Do `__repr__ = __str__` and it will work. You don't need to define a separate method this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python \_\_str\_\_ and lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727761/python-str-and-lists)

Comment: I see, i have been using the wrong data type! Thanks! @MadPhysicist