# Why is map(str, self.my_list) calling __repr__ on elements of my_list instead of __str__?

Tags: python

I've read through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727761/python-str-and-lists), and everyone seems in agreement that mapping `str` to a list should call `element.__str__` on each element of that list, but `__repr__` is being called instead.  I've stepped through the code, and the list is being generated properly.

My Collection wrapper looks like this:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.foo = list(args)

    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join(map(str, self.foo))
```

From `Wrapper.__str__()`, it jumps to `__repr__` in the contained class.  That class looks like this:

```
class MyType:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        # set the other values

    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a repr"

    def __str__(self):
        return "I am a str"
```

When I step through the code with a debugger, execution jumps directly from the map line in `Wrapper` to `__repr__` in `MyType`.  If I call `str(wrapper_instance.foo[0])`, I jump to `__str__` instead.  Why might this be?

EDIT: Wrapper is a superclass of the actual type that's being called, though the subclass doesn't implements a `__str__`.  The subclass definition looks like this:

```
class SubWrapper(Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, definite_arg, *args):
        super().__init__(args)
        self.definite_arg = definite_arg

    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a subclass repr"
```

In order to comply with the off-topic rule and to answer some of the questions about how the code is being called, the specific calls I'm making are:

```
>>> w = Wrapper(MyType(1, 2, 3), MyType(4, 5, 6))
>>> s = SubWrapper(MyType(7, 8, 9), MyType(1, 2, 3), MyType(4, 5, 6))
>>> print(str(w))
I am a str, I am a str
>>> print(str(s))
(I am a repr, I am a repr)
>>> print(", ".join(map(str, w.foo)))
I am a str, I am a str
>>> print(", ".join(map(str, s.foo)))
(I am a repr, I am a repr)
```

EDIT_2: It turns out that the issue was in the construction of the class - `SubWrapper.__init__` should call `super().__init__(*args)`

Comment: `print(Wrapper(MyType(1,2,3), MyType(1,2,3)))` works exactly as expected.  Are you instead using `print(Wrapper([MyType(1,2,3), MyType(1,2,3)]))`

Comment: Cannot reproduce - if I fix the error in `MyType` (`self,` not `self.`) then do `print(Wrapper(MyType(1,2,3), MyType(4,5,6)))` I get `I am a str, I am a str`. I helps to have a running example and its output for us to compare.

Comment: @tdelaney and @donkopotamus, I added some more information to the question as well as the solution - I never dereferenced (I'm sure there's a python term for that, but I don't know it) `*args` when calling the constructor.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ouch! Glad it worked out. I call that unpacking... but I'm not sure if that's official either.

Answer (score 0):

If you print a built-in container it will use the representation of each item <sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> [MyType(), MyType()]
[I am a repr, I am a repr]

>>> print([MyType(), MyType()])
[I am a repr, I am a repr]

>>> Wrapper(MyType(), MyType()).foo
[I am a repr, I am a repr]
```

However if you `map` each element to a string then it will (obviously) use the string representation:

```
>>> ','.join(map(str, [MyType(), MyType()]))
'I am a str,I am a str'

>>> print(Wrapper(MyType(), MyType()))
I am a str, I am a str
```

So items inside a built-in container (like `list`) will be displayed with the `__repr__` no matter if you use `str` or `repr` on the container. You explicitly need to convert each item so it's displayed using its `__str__` method.

---

<sup>1</sup> I removed the `__init__` method from your `MyType`. This just makes the code snippets "shorter" and less convolved.